# Error messages from react-hook-form with zod

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I created a customer registration form, but all my "messages" from my "errors" are coming as required. Does anyone know what it could be? Something I set up wrong in zod or react-hook-form. Below I will leave the prints of the code.

This is my generic input component:

```
import { DetailedHTMLProps, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react'

interface InputProps
  extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
    HTMLInputElement
  > {
  label: string
  error?: string
}

export const Input = ({ error, label, ...rest }: InputProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <label
        className="mb-2 block text-sm font-bold text-zinc-700"
        htmlFor={rest.id}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        className={`appearance-none rounded-md border border-zinc-300 px-3 py-2 leading-tight shadow-sm focus:border-zinc-500 focus:outline-none
        ${error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-zinc-300'}`}
        {...rest}
      />
      {error && <span className="text-xs text-red-500">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is where I created my schema and where I am using this generic input component inside the form:

```
import { Input } from '../Input'
import { Modal } from '../Modal'

import { z } from 'zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'

interface ClientRegistrationModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean
  onClose: () => void
}

const createUserFormSchema = z.object({
  name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, 'Password must be at least 2 characters long')
    .transform((name) =>
      name
        .trim()
        .split(' ')
        .map((word) => {
          return word[0].toLocaleUpperCase().concat(word.substring(1))
        })
        .join(' '),
    ),
  email: z
    .string()
    .email('Invalid e-mail format')
    .nonempty('E-mail is required'),
  birthdate: z.string().nonempty('Date of birth is mandatory'),
  cpf: z.string().length(11, 'CPF mus have 11 digits'),
})

type CreateUserFormData = z.infer<typeof createUserFormSchema>

export const ClientRegistrationModal = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
}: ClientRegistrationModalProps) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    reset,
  } = useForm<CreateUserFormData>({
    mode: 'all',
    resolver: zodResolver(createUserFormSchema),
  })

  // High-order function
  function createUser(data: CreateUserFormData) {
    console.log(data)
  }

  function resetForm() {
    onClose()
    reset()
  }

  console.log(errors)

  return (
    <Modal title="Cadastro de Cliente" isOpen={isOpen} onClose={resetForm}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(createUser)}>
        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-6">
          <Input
            label="Nome"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            {...register('name')}
            error={errors.name?.message}
          />

          <Input
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
            {...register('email')}
            error={errors.email?.message}
          />

          <Input
            label="Data de Nascimento"
            type="date"
            id="birthdate"
            {...register('birthdate')}
            error={errors.birthdate?.message}
          />

          <Input
            label="CPF"
            type="text"
            id="cpf"
            placeholder="Enter your CPF"
            {...register('cpf')}
            error={errors.cpf?.message}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
          <button
            className="mt-4 rounded bg-green-500 px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white transition-all ease-in hover:bg-green-700"
            type="submit"
          >
            Cadastrar
          </button>
          <button
            type="reset"
            className="mt-4 rounded bg-zinc-500 px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white transition-all ease-in hover:bg-zinc-700"
            onClick={resetForm}
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          >
            Cancelar
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

**The problem here is**, when I give console.log(errors), **my errors are all as "Required"**, that is, they are not showing the error messages that I set inside my schema.

I don't know what could be wrong and would like some help. Maybe it's some typing issue or something I configured wrong. I appreciate any help.

Instead of using that:
`name: z.string().min(2, 'The name needs at least 2 characters')`

I used this:
`name: z.string().min(2,{ message: 'The name needs at least 2 characters' })`

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

I was facing the same problem and it had to do with a bad setup between my custom `Input` component and the `{...register("name")}` props. Try changing your input to the standard `<input />` component and see if the game changes... it probably will.

Honestly I have no idea why spreading the `{...register("name")}` is causing problems, but it is. Here's a fixed version of your component, all I did different was passing down the `register` function as a Prop and calling it inside the Input (Maybe you should rename the component to `InputForm` cus it's now a pretty specific component that only works with such function)

I also decided to pass down the `name` as a prop so we can properly call `register`. For convenience we can also infer the error messages with the `name` prop.

```
import { type DetailedHTMLProps, type InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import {
  type FieldErrors,
  type FieldValues,
  type Path,
  type UseFormRegister,
} from "react-hook-form";

interface InputProps<FormData extends FieldValues>
  extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
    HTMLInputElement
  > {
  label: string;
  name: Path<FormData>;
  register: UseFormRegister<FormData>;
  errors: FieldErrors<FormData>;
}

export const Input = <FormData extends FieldValues>({
  label,
  name,
  errors,
  register,
  ...rest
}: InputProps<FormData>) => {
  const error = errors?.[name]?.message as string | undefined;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <label
        className="mb-2 block text-sm font-bold text-zinc-700"
        htmlFor={rest.id}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        className={`appearance-none rounded-md border border-zinc-300 px-3 py-2 leading-tight shadow-sm focus:border-zinc-500 focus:outline-none
        ${error ? "border-red-500" : "border-zinc-300"}`}
        {...rest}
        {...register(name)}
      />
      {error && <span className="text-xs text-red-500">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Usage of the component

```
<Input
  label="Nome"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter your name"
  name="name"
  errors={errors}
  register={register}
/>

<Input
  label="Email"
  type="email"
  name="email"
  placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
  errors={errors}
  register={register}
/>
// ... and so forth
```

Here's the result:
[image]

### Workaround

If you still want to keep you component that way, there's a workaround, you'll need to specify your message in more than one place.

What's happening is that `zod` and `react-hook-form` generate different error messages depending on the situation, which is a great feature actually. So the error type that it is firing for you does not come from the message you've set in `min()` but from the `z.string()` part of the zod schema:

```
  name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, 'Password must be at least 2 characters long')
```

So to fix that, let's specify a custom message for the `required_error` in the `string()`

```
  name: z
    .string({ required_error: 'Passoword is required' })
    .min(2, 'Password must be at least 2 characters long')
```

Now you'll have a better error message when the form is submitted with an `empty` name field.

For anyone facing a similar problem but not exactly this one, I recommend logging the error message that is coming from `react-hook-form` so you can investigate where your error is coming from, that's how I figured how to fix this problem.

You can do that by passing a second parameter in the `handleSubmit` function and using that to log your error:

```
const onFormError:SubmitErrorHandler<CreateUserFormData> = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
}

// Pass down this function in the handleSubmit
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(createUser, onFormError)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when using `zod` with `react-hook-form`. Even though i added custom message in zod object but still im getting error message as `Required`. after searching through the net i found this  [article](https://dev.to/texmeijin/component-design-idea-using-react-hook-form-v7-ie0).

In the article i found out this `` errors={errors["name"] && `${(errors["name"] as DeepMap<FieldValues, FieldError>).message}`} ``
and it worked for me

```
<Input
  label="Nome"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter your name"
  name="name"
  errors={errors["name"] && `${(errors["name"] as DeepMap<FieldValues, FieldError>).message}`}
  register={register}
/>
```

`DeepMap` is a package from `react-hook-form`

reference:
https://www.react-hook-form.com/ts/#FieldErrors